# Change qty input to the counter of the number of products on mini-cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, mini-cart, qty, count

How to change qty input to the counter of the number of products.

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite file

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

to

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

and add `<p data-bind="html: qty">`